# React, using emojis in a drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I've been working on a little game in react and part of the game allows for the player to set some settings before starting.  It's a turn-based tag game, four players chase different tokens around the map, while avoiding the one player labeled "it".

I have the following render method for a select option:

```js
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.createPlayers} ref="form">
                <label htmlFor="goodies">Choose a Goody!</label>
                <select name="goodies" id="goodies">
                    <option value="donut"></option>
                    <option value="cookie"></option>
                    <option value="hotdog"></option>
                    <option value="bacon"></option>
                    <option value="hamburger"></option>
                    <option value="brocolli"></option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Play!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I get a large warning saying I need to wrap them in span elements, add some aria labels and give them a role of error.

`Line 18:  Emojis should be wrapped in <span>, have role="img", and have an accessible description with aria-label or aria-labelledby  jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji`

I do that, and then the JSX refuses to compile because it's expect a string for each option.  It won't let me put a span between the option tags.

I'd really like to get this warning to go away, but when I try to do what it asks, the JSX won't compile.  Is there something I have to do to make this work without the warning?

Thing is, I used emojis elsewhere and I got no warnings or any problems whatsoever.

Comment: Have you tried `<span role="img" aria-labelledby="panda1"></span>`?

Comment: As I said, if I do that, the JSX won't compile.

Comment: Remove the `accessible-emoji` rule from your `.eslintrc` configuration file.

Answer (score 20):

Add in select `<span role="img" aria-label="xxxxx">` like this

```
 <select name="goodies" id="goodies">
    <option value="donut">
       <span role="img" aria-label="donut"></span> 
   </option>
   ....
  </select>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: You might wanna create a component for Emoji like following with `<option>` tag in the Emoji component

```js
    const Emoji = props => (
  <option
    className="emoji"
    role="img"
    aria-label={props.label ? props.label : ""}
    aria-hidden={props.label ? "false" : "true"}
    value={props.label}
  >
    {props.symbol}
  </option>
)

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (    
      <div> 
        <form onSubmit={this.createPlayers} ref="form">
            <label htmlFor="goodies">Choose a Goody!</label>
            <select onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e.target.value)}} name="goodies" id="goodies">
               <Emoji label="donut" symbol="" />
               <Emoji label="cookie" symbol="" />  
               <Emoji label="hotdog" symbol="" />   
               <Emoji label="bacon" symbol="" />  
               <Emoji label="hamburger" symbol="" />   
               <Emoji label="brocolli" symbol="" />                    
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Play!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
          
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: If I do that, I end up with [object Object] in my drop down.

Comment: It does on my end! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

A way that I found to use emojis with react is the following syntax based on emoji's Unicode.

Try this:

```
{`\u{1f369}`}
```

So your code would be like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.createPlayers} ref="form">
                <label htmlFor="goodies">Choose a Goody!</label>
                <select name="goodies" id="goodies">
                    <option value="donut">{`\u{1f369}`}</option>
                    <option value="cookie">{`\u{1f36a}`}</option>
                    <option value="hotdog">{`\u{1f32d}`}</option>
                    <option value="bacon">{`\u{1f953}`}</option>
                    <option value="hamburger">{`\u{1f354}`}</option>
                    <option value="brocolli">{`\u{1f966}`}</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Play!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[It may not work for every emoji.](https://medium.com/@seanmcp/%EF%B8%8F-how-to-use-emojis-in-react-d23bbf608bf7)

Comment: Not sure about the `{\`` thing though, i just used `\u{<unicode>}`.

Answer (score -1):

> error :  Emojis should be wrapped in , have role="img", and have
> an accessible description with aria-label or aria-labelledby
> jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji

Try this:

```
<span role="img" aria-label="emoji name">  </span>
```